# How to make a cancel button that will undo what you type on the textfields in angularjs?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Sorry, I'm really new to this. I hope someone would help me understand how to undo a textfield after I put data in it.

I have client.js----

```
this.client = {
        id: '',
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        age: '',
        new: true
    };

    function cancel() {
        clientService.cancel(vm.client);
        getClients();
        //clear();
    }
```

and clientService.js

```
function cancel(client) {
        //newValue[] = clients;
        //cancel_lagi = function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
        //clients.new = 'New Value :' + clients.newValue;
        //clients.old = 'Old Value :' + $scopes.oldValue;
        //clients.oldvalue = oldvalue;
        //client.newValue = oldvalue;

        //--------This doesn't do anything 

        //}
    }
```

and my client.html

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-ng-click="cancel()">
```

after the user will try to edit a data from the local storage when he/she clicks the cancel button it will return to its previous value.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve minimal, complete, and verifiable example. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask good questions.

Comment: Noted and I'm done updating my question Sir. Will you be so kind to help me with my problem Sir?

Answer (score 0):

Try this is your controller. You are going to copy the data before it's changed and use it to revert back on a cancel.

```
angular.module('mymodule').controller('MyController', MyController);

/** @ngInject */
function MyController(MyService) {

   var vm = this;

   // However you get the data from your service, not important
   vm.data = MyService.getData();

   // This is where you will save a copy of your data
   var savedData = null;

   vm.edit = function(data) {
      // This is important: this creates a copy of the 
      // data so you my revert back to it on the cancel method
      savedData = angular.copy(data);

      // See HTML below: vm.data.property should be bound to the 
      // ng-model attribute of a given form control.
   };

   vm.save = function(data) {
      // However you save your data, not important.
      MyService.save(data);

      // Set savedData to null as we don't need it anymore.
      savedData = null;
   };

   vm.cancel = function(data) {
      // Important: set the data back to original.
      data = angular.copy(savedData);

      // Set savedData to null again
      savedData = null;
   };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">

   <button ng-click="vm.edit(vm.data)">Edit</button>

   <form>
      <!-- 
        the vm.data.firstName is bound here and changes to it 
        will be reflected in the controller's vm.data. In fact,
        they are the same. 
      -->
      <input type="text" ng-model="vm.data.firstName" />

     <!-- save will save the data to your service -->
     <button ng-click="vm.save(vm.data)">Save</button>

     <-- cancel will revert vm.data back to it's original values -->
     <button ng-click="vm.cancel(vm.data)">Cancel</button>

   </form>

</div>
```

This is not a complete example and probably contains errors, however the take away is to copy the data before you use it in the form, then if you cancel, reset the form data with the copy you made.

Comment: Thank you so much for the precise and detailed answer, sir. I will try it soon to finished our activity ^_^